# external jQuery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, external

My code works inside an html but not from an external .js file.

In my external .js, I have a function like .animate() and hide() etc. working fine but
just for functions like .text() or .html() it is not working in the external file.
I even deleted all my code and just kept this script, still it didn't work, but when I copy pasted into my html it worked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        

    </head>


    <body >
        <div id="demo"> --- </div>
        <button>click me</button>

    </body>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("#demo").html("text");
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Wrap your click event handler with `$(document).ready(function() { your code });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your JS

```
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("#demo").html("text");
    });
});
```

Comment: i copy past your code in my .js doesn't work
im sure i did something bad :/
Because your answer is LOGIC

Comment: @cid-wings check your .js path whether correct or wrong

Comment: hahahahahahahahahahahaahhahahahaahahahahahahahahahahahahah
im going crazy for the last hours beceause of that ahhahahaha
<script src="js/red01.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
and my file name was red.js

Comment: thx fergoso your answer was the correct one 
and i still dont know how come a part of my code working with wrong path and the rest no :/

Answer (score 0):

your html code is fully messed up!! update your code with the below

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>    
<body>
    <div id="demo"> --- </div>
    <button>click me</button>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("button").on("click", function() {
                $("#demo").html("text");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: i know i just copy past my code from dreamweaver CS6
and in my html is work i just want to making this script work an a external .js